# When to encode as HTML in Grails

Tags: html, grails, encoding

I often see Grails sample code where the programmer has called a method called `encodeAsHTML()`. I figure I should probably use this in my Grails applications (for security reasons, I assume?), but I was wondering *when* I should use this method. What objects/properties/etc. are candidates for the `encodeAsHTML()` method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `encodeAsHTML()` (or `encodeAsJavaScript`, etc) for everything that you've got from user. For every *string* that could be modified by user (got from input form, from request parameter, from external API call, etc)

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure when this was introduced to Grails, but if in `Config.groovy` you set `grails.views.default.codec="html"` then `encodeAsHTML()` is called whenever you use `${}` in GSPs.

Source: http://alwaysthecritic.typepad.com/atc/2010/06/grails-gsp-html-escaping-confusion.html